# How to keep a pointer to the original data in a tumbling window

Tags: xquery, xslt-2.0

Following my inital [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46500874/group-nodes-within-the-same-time-preriod) with simplified data, I try to adapt the given solution to my actual data.

I face now this problem: 
what is the best way to group the `<time>` nodes (as [anwsered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46500874/group-nodes-within-the-same-time-preriod)) and keep a pointer to the source document. Preciselly, I need to access the parent node `<trkpt>` to copy the attributes in the output.

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx 
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
creator="me" 
version="1.1" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 gpx.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <link href="http://www.garmin.com">
            <text>Garmin International</text>
        </link>
        <time>2017-08-03T11:26:14Z</time>
    </metadata>
    <trk>
        <name>Journal actif: 01 AOUT 2017 16:03</name>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="50.064145" lon="5.194660">
                <ele>305.84</ele>
                <time>2017-08-01T15:25:58Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.062084" lon="5.198431">
                <ele>314.49</ele>
                <time>2017-08-01T15:26:11Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.059504" lon="5.202687">
                <ele>321.70</ele>
                <time>2017-08-01T15:26:27Z</time>
            </trkpt>
        </trkseg>
    </trk>
    <trk>
        <name>Journal actif: 01 AOUT 2017 17:26</name>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="50.058567" lon="5.203909">
                <ele>323.62</ele>
                <time>2017-08-01T15:26:32Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.055699" lon="5.207007">
                <ele>330.35</ele>
                <time>2017-08-01T15:26:46Z</time>
            </trkpt>            
        </trkseg>
    </trk>
</gpx>
```

Expected Output (partial view)

```
<trkseg>
    <trkpt lat="50.064145" lon="5.194660">
        <time>2017-08-03T11:26:14Z</time>
    </trkpt>
```

My current xslt is as follow
It breaks at the line `<xsl:attribute name="lat" select="../@lat"/>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?altova_samplexml file:///C:/Data/Google%20Drive/Projects%20-%20Coding/Xslt/Garmin/01.xml?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
    <xsl:param name="stop" as="xs:dayTimeDuration" select="xs:dayTimeDuration('PT5M')"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(trk)*">
        <xsl:param name="dateTimes" as="xs:dateTime*"/>
        <xsl:param name="stop" as="xs:dayTimeDuration"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group($dateTimes[1], $dateTimes[position() gt 1], $stop)"/>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(trk)*">
        <xsl:param name="group" as="xs:dateTime*"/>
        <xsl:param name="dateTimes" as="xs:dateTime*"/>
        <xsl:param name="stop" as="xs:dayTimeDuration"/>
        <xsl:variable name="next" as="xs:dateTime?" select="$dateTimes[1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="end" as="xs:dateTime" select="$group[last()]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(exists($next))">
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:wrap($group)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$next - $end gt $stop">
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:wrap($group)"/>
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:group($next, $dateTimes[position() gt 1], $stop)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(($group, $next), $dateTimes[position() gt 1], $stop)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:function name="mf:wrap" as="element(trk)">
        <xsl:param name="dateTimes" as="xs:dateTime*"/>
        <trk xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
            <name>TBC</name>
            <trkseg>
                <xsl:for-each select="$dateTimes">
                    <trkpt>
                    <xsl:attribute name="lat" select="../@lat"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="lon" select="../@lon"/>
                        <time>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </time>
                    </trkpt>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </trkseg>
        </trk>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:template match="gpx">
        <gpx 
        xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        creator="me" 
        version="1.1" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 gpx.xsd">
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(.//trkpt/time/xs:dateTime(.), $stop)"/>
        </gpx>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you would need to rewrite the functions to pass on and handle the elements (like the `trkpt` elements) and then inside the functions you would need to compute the `xs:dateTime` for the comparison), here is an attempt to fix the functions, I haven't tested that thouroughly though:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
    <xsl:param name="stop" as="xs:dayTimeDuration" select="xs:dayTimeDuration('PT5M')"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(trk)*">
        <xsl:param name="trktpts" as="element(trkpt)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="stop" as="xs:dayTimeDuration"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group($trktpts[1], $trktpts[position() gt 1], $stop)"/>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(trk)*">
        <xsl:param name="group" as="element(trkpt)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="trkpts" as="element(trkpt)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="stop" as="xs:dayTimeDuration"/>
        <xsl:variable name="next" as="element(trkpt)?" select="$trkpts[1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="nextDateTime" as="xs:dateTime?" select="$next/time/xs:dateTime(.)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="end" as="xs:dateTime" select="$group[last()]/time/xs:dateTime(.)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(exists($next))">
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:wrap($group)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$nextDateTime - $end gt $stop">
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:wrap($group)"/>
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:group($next, $trkpts[position() gt 1], $stop)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(($group, $next), $trkpts[position() gt 1], $stop)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:function name="mf:wrap" as="element(trk)">
        <xsl:param name="trkpts" as="element(trkpt)*"/>
        <trk>
            <name>TBC</name>
            <trkseg>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$trkpts"/>
            </trkseg>
        </trk>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="trkpt/ele"/>

    <xsl:template match="gpx">
        <gpx 
            creator="me" 
            version="1.1" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 gpx.xsd">
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(.//trkpt, $stop)"/>
        </gpx>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Oh nooo! I cannot get rid of the error "instruction stack overflow" (altova 2010).
I have splitted my input file to get the smallest one (~5600 trkpt for 1 trip), but I still get this nasty error.

Comment: Ask in the Altova support or forum whether/how you can increase the the recursion limit if that is the cause of the problem. If that doesn't solve the problem I would suggest to try Saxon 9, the open source HE edition is available for the Java and .NET platform and opens up the way to the XQuery 3 or XSLT 3 solutions I posted earlier if the XSLT 2.0 recursive function used above also poses problem with Saxon.

Comment: In general to avoid a stack overflow with recursive functions you can try to change its implementation using a technique called "divide and conquer", see https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200912/msg00213.html for details so that would be another option if you really need to do this with XSLT 2.0.

Comment: I gave a try with the latest version of Altova (2017, free for 1 month), and it has processed all my data with no error.